# How to calculate the difference between 2 numbers in Excel (harder than you might expect ;-)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is probably painfully easy to solve but I have been fiddling with it for a while now and can't seem to solve it.

Column `A` hold the market return, column `B` the return of a certain stock. I want to calculate the excess market return: how many $ has the stock performed better than the market? In column `C`, I have calculated the values by hand:

```
  .      A       B       C
 ---------------------------
 1   -2.22    0.17    2.39
 2   -2.99    0.57    3.56     both the market as the stock have lost, but the
 3  -11.68   -0.40   11.28 <-- stock has lost 11.28 less than the market has
 4    6.16    0.06   -6.10 <-- compared to the market, the stock underperformed
 5    0.94   -0.22   -1.16      by 6.10
 6    7.45    0.17   -7.28
 7   -1.96   -0.07    1.89
```

You can't just simply extract `A1` from `B1`, or vice versa. I'm confused; who isn't and knows what formula to use in `C1;C7` to get the right answers?

Comment: It looks pretty easy to me :), except how you arrived at #5.  By the way, a question like this should be asked on SuperUser.

Comment: Yeah why can't you simply subtract the columns?  I don't see any reason why not except that row 5 throws a wrench into everything because it makes no sense at all.

Comment: @DougGlancy: formulas as are almost like programming. Well, people definitely write 'programs' in them :P.

Comment: OK, Sorry everybody, as expected I totally missed the obvous here. I'm off to bed, thanks anyways :-)

Comment: @MichałGórny, I basically agree.  It's a gray line, but I think this one was over it.

Comment: `=B1-A1` is *not* programming

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should work:

```
=B1-A1
```

Comment: This is painfull, as expected. I'm off to bed...this is just embarrassing.